# Parse error on nested javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Im trying to nest java script in a php echo tag. Im getting this error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'

How can i nest that java script in that echo tag properly?

```
if($rowCount%5===0) { 
    echo '</table><br/><br/><script type='text/javascript' src='http://ads.com'></script><br/><br/><table align="center" width="70%"><tr>'; 
    $rowCount = 0; 
}
```

Comment: Escape your quotes `\'text/javascript\'` or use double quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your quote is not escaped yet. escape your ' string with \'

Answer (score 4):

You mixed up the quotes:

```
echo '</table><br/><br/><script type="text/javascript" src="http://ads.com"></script><br/><br/><table align="center" width="70%"><tr>';
```

You should use double quotes- `"` inside of a single quote`'` strings or escape the single quote with `\`

Answer (score 1):

You can either escape your quote characters inside the php string, or else use double quote (") inside the string.